# Angular, rxjs: can we add something like a template variable to a rxjs subject so that data streams are routed based on where they should go?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am a newbie to the angular, rxjs area. I was working with a Subject observable to accept data from one component (angular) and send to another component. I was wondering if there was a way we could create a message analogous to an email and send a data stream to many recipients but only the intended ones.

Typing this, I think it might have been a naive question to ask, but I am going with the "no question is stupid" analogy.

Comment: Rxjs is pull , you are asking to push. In the sense there is one guy who has info , whomever interested can go and subscribe to him for updates (like twitter or blog subscriptions ) . What you are asking is mail , send to specific people, it won't work that way in my opinion.

Comment: But with subject.next we can basically push?

Comment: You are saying this is the new value , you are not deciding who can see that . Push is when you say , observer1.update(), observer2.update() , specifically choosing whom to send your updates .